# issue with using should quote in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, quote, csvhelper

I am facing some issue using csvHelper library. I have attached my class object. I want string and dateTime typed data will be quoted only.

I know I need to update the  csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote  option. but don't know how.

```
static void Main()
        {      
            var recordNew = new List<Metadata>
             {
                 new Metadata { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), VersionNumber = 100, CreatedOn=DateTime.Now, Name = "two", AccountSequene=90, IsPublic=false}
             };

            writeDataTest(recordNew);

        }

        private static void writeDataTest(List<Metadata> records)
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
               csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
               csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) =>
               {
                    return context.Record.Count == 1;
                };
               csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MetadataMap>();
               csv.WriteRecords(records);
               var s = writer.ToString();

            }
        }


        public class Metadata
        {
            public Guid? Id { get; set; }
            public long? VersionNumber { get; set; }
            public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public long? AccountSequene { get; set; }
            public bool? IsPublic { get; set; }
        }
        public class MetadataMap : ClassMap<Metadata>
        {
            public MetadataMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Id).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.VersionNumber).Index(1);
                Map(m => m.CreatedOn).Index(2).ConvertUsing(m => $"\"{m.CreatedOn}\"");
                Map(m => m.Name).Index(3).ConvertUsing(m => $"\"{m.Name}\"");
                Map(m => m.Email).Index(4).ConvertUsing(m => $"\"{m.Email}\"");
                Map(m => m.AccountSequene).Index(5);
                Map(m => m.IsPublic).Index(6);
            }
        }
```

currently I am getting the result as

> 74d5c276-0e5f-442b-a392-cd8fb37c4114,"100","4/12/2019 2:11:40 PM","two","",90,False

100 is quoted as  I set return context.Record.Count == 1; But my expected result is

> 74d5c276-0e5f-442b-a392-cd8fb37c4114,100,"4/12/2019 2:11:40 PM","two",,90,False

in the expected result as string Email is not provided so I want it like ("two",,90 instead of "two","",90)

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is possibly easier to read, but just in case you wanted to use `ShouldQuote`. I found where Josh Close had shown [how to quote specific indexes](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1221).  Remove the `ConvertUsing()` statements in the ClassMap and set `ShouldQuote` like this.

```cs
var indexes = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };
csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => indexes.Contains(context.Record.Count) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field);
```

Comment: Thanks David. This solution is definitely better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the codes as follows:

```
`private static void writeDataTest(List<Metadata> records)
    {
             ......
           csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) =>
           {
                return false;
           };
           ......
     } 

     public class MetadataMap : ClassMap<Metadata>
    { .....
         Map(m => m.Email).Index(4).ConvertUsing(m => m.Email != null ? $"\"{m.Email}\"" : $"{m.Email}"); 
    ....}
```

`